# Android:Draw line on a textview

Tags: android, drawable, textview

I have asked a question previously titled "Android: Ruled/horizonal lines in TextView" at [Android: Ruled/horizonal lines in Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748467/android-ruled-horizonal-lines-in-textview) . But I haven't got required answer. So I'm planing to do this by drawing line on TextView by java.Is there any way to draw Line inside TextView? or if I get end of line from java code then I'll be able to add textview for each line. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm using the technique of  drawing lines between each line of text in **EditText** and then I will make the **EditText** non-editable by setting **setKeyListener(null)** to the custom EditText object so that, the EditText acts like a **TextView** :)

---

### A custom EditText that draws lines between each line of text that is displayed:

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x800000FF);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int count = getLineCount();
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

---

Now use object of **LinedEditText** class where you need your **TextView** and make it non-editable.

### An Example:

```
public class HorizontalLine extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Android: Ruled/horizonal lines in Textview");

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinedEditText et = new LinedEditText(this, null);
        et.setText("The name of our country is Bangladesh. I am proud of my country :)");
        et.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);
        et.setKeyListener(null);

        ll.addView(et);
        this.setContentView(ll);

    }

}
```

---

**et.setKeyListener(null)** makes the EditText non-editable so, it acts like a TextView.

---

### The Output:

[image]

### Issue with cursor:

If you use **et.setKeyListener(null)** only then it is just not listening to keys but
user can see a cursor on the EditText. If you don't want this cursor just disable the EditText by adding this line:

```
 et.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to make the textview a drawable canvas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you want a line inside a textview. If you want to draw a horizontal single line just put this code between the textviews that you are reading from the db, obviously in your layout xml file:

`<View android:background="#colorYouWant" android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" android:id="+@id/horizontalLine"/>`

Adjust the separation by java coding doing this in the related java code:

```
View horizontalLine = (View)findViewById(R.id.horizontalLine);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
horizontalLine.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The left, top, right, bottom parameters are the ones that you have to change.