# How to make a Edit Note with paper line in Android?

Tags: android

I want to make a edit note and draw a paper line in background of that. Like the image below (as you can see, either vertical and horizontal line):

[image]

I don't know how can I draw it and how can I repeat it?

Comment: If your just drawing lines why can't you use a canvas?

Comment: How can I use a canvas? could you tell me a sample from a picture with multi line?

Comment: It seems like this is a feature that is currently lacking within an ImageView.  I suspect you'll need to create your own View class to handle the repeating drawing on your own.

Comment: Why not create a background image? that should work perfect.

Comment: my friend, I can't use ImageView because of I want to change height between lines regard to fontsize. so I can't use them :-(

Comment: PNG 9 patch fit your needs.

Comment: people, there is no need create new view or 9patch, just extend textview class

Comment: how come? please more explain or show example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770670/619673

Of course you can implement it in textview (linked topic is about edittext) but it is quite the same operation (i think :D ).
To use it in your xml you have to write instead of `TextView` your package path to custom widget class i.e. `com.example.notepad.linkededit`

[image]

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.notepadline.LinedEditText
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="AAAA AAAA AAA AAAA AAAA AAA AAAA AAAA AAA AAAA AAAA AAA AAAA AAAA AAA AAAA AAAA AAA" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The rest of information is in reference link.