# EditText like Note

Tags: android, android-edittext, notepad

I am developing Android Application like Note App. All of things were going pretty well.Here my output.

[image]

But, I have facing a problem that is the lines in my EditText become unequal with text when I typed Myanmar Language (one of South East Asia Language), here my output,

[image]
I googled and try many ways. But, it can't help me. Below are my code. Kindly!

**LinedEditText.java**

```
public class LinedEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x800000FF);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 2, r.right, baseline + 2, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

}
```

**actvity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Title Here" />

    <login.fb.ucsy.com.notepad.LinedEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_story"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:minLines="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone"
        android:text="Story : \n"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use third party library for it. Search that library in Android-Arsanal.com

Comment: Could you pls tell me in little detail? @KrunalKapadiya

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin check this http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=210c4b53-1040-4afc-a060-df8b2cba009d.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Edit Note with paper line in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912163/how-to-make-a-edit-note-with-paper-line-in-android)

Comment: @Nilesh, these of all, I have been tested. It is working for English language but not working with Myanmar language. Anyway,thanks