# Android Custom TextView dotted line

Tags: android

I am trying from many day but did not get any solution . i have refer this
[Android:Draw line on a textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754265/androiddraw-line-on-a-textview)
I have tried to create dotted line in text view , done with it , working fine , but i want to add dotted line till length of the text that text view contain , If Text View have one line text then it work fine But if text view have multi line text then for the line which have text half or less then screen width then also dotted line appear with i dont want.... 
I draw dotted line using Paint ...please help me ....
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code what u've done so far . . .

Comment: mPaint = new Paint();
  mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  mPaint.setDither(true);
  mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000); 
  mPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{ 3, 3, }, 0));
  mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);..
this code  to draw dotted line and in OnDraw to check number of line i have done this thing   for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    int baseLine = getLineBounds(i, r);
    
    canvas.drawLine(0,  baseLine + 1, r.right,  baseLine + 1, mPaint);
    

   }

Comment: Do you want each line highlighted in multiline `TextView`?

Comment: i want to underline (dotted line) below text , means below character of textview

Comment: Do you want the dotted line? Or a smooth line is also fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the topic, in which you do, try to write in the constructor of the class `LinedEditText`

```
mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,10}, 0));
```

instead of

```
mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(0x800000FF);
```

**EDIT:**

and tell me please again, do you want like this:

[image: underline the whole of textView]

or this:

[image: underline each line]

**EDIT:**

MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    String text = "Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample";

    LinedEditText et = new LinedEditText(this, null, text);
    et.setText(text);
    et.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);
    et.setKeyListener(null);

    ll.addView(et);

    this.setContentView(ll);
}
```

LinedEditText:

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;
String text;

public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String text) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.text = text;

    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 10 }, 0));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;

    int lineCount = getLineCount();
    int size = getLayout().getLineStart(lineCount-1);

    String str = getText().toString().substring(size);

    float densityMultiplier = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float scaledPx = 20 * densityMultiplier;
    paint.setTextSize(scaledPx);
    float i = paint.measureText(str);

    for (int k = 0; k < lineCount-1; k++) {
        int baseline = getLineBounds(k, r);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 2, r.right, baseline + 2, paint);
    }

    int baseline = getLineBounds(lineCount-1, r);
    canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 2, i, baseline + 2, paint);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

Comment: see may edits and answer about pictures please

Comment: last picture contains multi line with dash line , but last line which contain 2 words Sample Sample i want dash only for that two words

Comment: I found some solution, in the near future I will make it to the response

Comment: Thanks  Lia Pronina for your reply

Comment: Thanks  Lia Pronina... u have done great job....:)

Comment: Hi Lia Pronina ,if I use  TextView instead of EditText face same problem

Comment: Solved it, its my mistake.... 
Thanks

Comment: If everything was settled, can you check my answer as correct?

Comment: Hi Lia Pronina , can u tell me that ...is it possible to set background color of text only and not Text view..?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? Color of background or color of text? You can to write like this, if I understood you correct `<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ABABAB" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: u have given code to set dotted for text only , like that i want to set background color for that text only

Comment: create a new question for this, need some time to check out what you're asking, I can't say immediately. You can use `setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.ic_launcher);` in `LinedEditTextfor` for example.

Comment: I have create new question  , please make response if u know how to do that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584267/android-setbackground-color-for-custom-text-view

Comment: Hi Lia Pronina .. can u tell me how to differentiate multiple line in TextView ,if i set background color of textview