# How to make Android EditText text follow by a nice blue under line

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

I want a EditText as given in the picture bellow:-

[image]

Please suggest how to do this? Thanks in advance!

**Update:-**

I used  Nikita Kurtin's suggestion. It looks weird. I have to adjust the background. I guess this background needs to adjusted for variants of devices. See the picture what is the problem right now:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an xml for a line background and set it's attribute of tileMode as repeated. Then just use it as a background of your edit text.

example for an xml: 
asume it's called 'blue_lines.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap 
android:src="@drawable/blue_line_bg"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

example for editText using it:

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/input1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/blue_lines"

 />
```

[image]

**Update1**: blue line image I used
[image: blue line image]

**Update2**: dynamically calculated font, to adjust different screens

First: get the height of blue_line_bg

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue_line_bg, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int padding=10;//inner line padding
    int fontSize=imageHeight-padding;//calculated font size
```

Second: add calculated font size to the relevant editText

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.input1)).setTextSize(fontSize);//set calculated font size to the edit text
```

Comment: Could you please give the blue_line_bg image? I couldn't make or find any suitable blue line image for background. I tried it and works with my crappy background blue line image :(.

Comment: No problem, I added it to the answer for you. As  you can see It's just a simple white rectangle with blue line at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. Please check the updated  comments

Comment: Yes to adjust to different screens the font size and the one-line background needs to be matched.  To solve this you can dynamically take the height of resources bitmap, and then add needed text size to the EditText. I've added example to the answer. @see Update 2 
Checked it in 2 real devices: Nexus 4 with API 5.0 and THL with 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

i highly recommend to use this lib for every line of your layout without helper text, floated label text and error text.
check lib:
https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Comment: It's nice but limited. Not backward compatible. So I can't use it. My app should support min  sdk level 16

Comment: This library is min sdk 12. https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/blob/master/sample/build.gradle
Not backward compatible means, its version 2, if you used version 1, then upgraded to version 2, you won't be able to go back to version 2. For your min sdk 16 requirements this library is good to go. I used this library, it's fantastic and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your edit text through java code, I haven't done this before but https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770670/1384010 is an example who is doing kind of same thing.You will need to make few changes in code for meeting with your actual requirements.

Hope this will help you mate.