# Draw horizontal line in android text view dynamically

Tags: android, textview

I have tried the following code to draw a horizontal line between two lines in text view:

```
String line1="<br>This is line 1</br>";
String line2="&nbsp;This is line 2";
String htmlCode =line1 +"<hr>"+line2;
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlCode));
```

I also tried:

```
    String line1="<br>This is line 1</br>";
    String line2="&nbsp;This is line 2";
    String htmlCode =line1 +"<span style='border-bottom:1px solid'</span>"+line2;
```

I am trying to store this code into database and further fetch the text and display in view.

```
String htmlCode= GetTextFromDB();
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlCode));
```

the horizontal line part/span with border is not working where all other markups like `br` and `&nbsp;` are working well

Comment: You want to underline text or put a line separator?

Comment: Read solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754265/androiddraw-line-on-a-textview/10770670#10770670. This is same as you need.

Comment: I have some texts stored in database. I just want to pick up those texts and write on view. So before storing them into database I am trying to add html markups.@prashant17

Answer (score 0):

```
View viewHorizontleLine = new View(this); v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      
        5 )); viewHorizontleLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A1A1A1"));

LinearLay.addView(viewHorizontleLine);
```

Try this one make a horizontal line programetically  hope this may help you

Comment: I have some texts stored in database. I just want to pick up those texts and write on view. So before storing them into database I am trying to add html markups.@InsaneCat

Comment: Edited my question in more detail@InsaneCat