# How can I have a row separating line in TextView

Tags: android

I want to have a line between each row in `TextView`.
Can original `TextView` do this?
If not, how can I do it?

[image: separating line]

---

ANSWER:

Thanks to @Slartibartfast reference and advice. I made a customized `TextView`. And I get something like this.

[image: textview with line separator]

This is what I want!

The code:

```
public class LinedTextView extends TextView {

private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

public LinedTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public LinedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();

}

public LinedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(0x800000ff);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int cnt = getLineCount();
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        int baseLine = getLineBounds(i, r);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseLine + 1, r.right, baseLine + 1, paint);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

Comment: use a listview with dividers.

Comment: use a background image.

Comment: You can either follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748467/android-ruled-horizonal-lines-in-textview and create a complex textview or do the simple thing like @Raghunandan says and use a list view

Comment: i think having a customized TextView will be my choice, rather than using a ListView with dividers or View below TextView. Because it will take me pains to separate the words in to each item of ListView. Thanks @Slartibartfast for your reference, that is really what i want!

Answer (score 3):

Use the following line of code below your `TextView`

```
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />
```

You can configure it according to your need.

You can also use `ListView` with divider.