# android : How to show a text inline another

Tags: android, textview

Is there any solution to have 2 textview like this :

[image](http://oi44.tinypic.com/2sbsx6o.jpg)

in fact i want to show Text2 lines below the Text1 lines. For exmple to show the translation Text1.

Any solution?

Comment: Just lay them out, one below the other. That is what layouts are for. You can do this easily with a RelativeLayout or a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Are you creating your TextViews in XML or programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setLineSpacing to set a big enough gap in your TextViews and overlap them, then translate it so one shows up in between the lines of the other.

Comment: Just to add some more detail, you'll have to adjust the margins on both TextViews and you'll want to use a layout that allows you to overlap Views as well as setting the View background to transparent but in on the whole this is probably one of the easiest ways of achieving the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. 
You can set lineSpacingExtra property of TextView and can use relative layout to overlap them. After this you cna set properties of your text view accordingly

```
In your xml define text view properties like this

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Text 1. This is Text1. This is Text 1. This is Text1. This is Text 1. This is Text1"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
        android:textColor="#5F4C0B"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="26dp"
        android:text="This is Text 2. This is Text2. This is Text2. This is Text2. This is Text2. This is Text2"
        android:textColor="#B40404"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You will get output like this

[image]

Accept the answer if you found it useful

Comment: Why should someone try your code? What solution you are suggesting to resolve particular issue? Include more detail to get up vote and appreciation. #Tip

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Paresh. I will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: Thanks. but what about Borders under the lines?

Comment: I think you have to use background of that type i.e. a white background with gray lines and set textview position accordingly or you can use use <u></u> tags to underline textview if it fulfills your requirement

Comment: Please try this link. I think this link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748467/android-ruled-horizonal-lines-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create this view,

In Main Activity write the following code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams text1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            text1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams text2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            text2.setMargins(0, 26, 0, 0);

            LinesTextView tv1 = new LinesTextView(this, null);
            tv1.setText("This is Text 1. This is Text 1. This is Text 1. This is Text 1. This is Text 1. This is Text 1.");
            tv1.setLineSpacing(20.0f, 1.0f);
            tv1.setLayoutParams(text1);
            tv1.setTextSize(24.0f);
            tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));

            LinesTextView tv2 = new LinesTextView(this, null);
            tv2.setText("This is Text 2. This is Text 2. This is Text 2. This is Text 2. This is Text 2. This is Text 2.");
            tv2.setLineSpacing(25.0f, 1.0f);
            tv2.setLayoutParams(text2);
            tv2.setTextSize(18.0f);
            tv2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            rl.addView(tv1);
            rl.addView(tv2);

            this.setContentView(rl);
        }
    }
```

In LinesTextView class write the following code

```
public class LinesTextView extends TextView
{
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinesTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x800000FF);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int count = getLineCount();
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Check Screen shot

[image]

Set Text color, style, margin and size accordingly.