# An EditText full of horizontal lines

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-canvas

Going over this SO answer [Android: Ruled/horizonal lines in Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748467/android-ruled-horizonal-lines-in-textview) and some code from the book that I am reading, I came up with this:

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        // color the paper
        canvas.drawColor(paperColor);

        // draw ruled lines
        int lineCount = getLineCount();
        Rect r = rect;
        for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++){
            int baseLine = getLineBounds(i, r);
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseLine+1, r.right, baseLine+1, linePaint);
        }

        // draw margin
        canvas.drawLine(margin, 0, margin, getMeasuredHeight(), marginPaint);

        // move the text across the margin
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(margin, 0);

        // render the text
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

However, though, I only get ruled lines if I add more lines of text to the `EditText`. This is because `getLineCount()` has been used. Basically, I want the `EditText` to look like a page from a notebook.

What modification to the code is needed?

Comment: just set a background Drawable, no need to extend an EditText

Comment: @pskink `9PatchDrawable`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `getLineCount()`, maybe you could do something like this:

```
private int getDrawableLineCount() {
   return getMeasuredHeight() % getLineHeight();
}
```

The line height may need adjusting, but that should get you started.